# How to use volume shadow copy using C# in vs2008

Tags: c#, .net, backup, restore, volume-shadow-service

I'd like to make a C# application that uses Volume Shadow Copy Service for backup/restore.

How do I access the VSS API from C#?

Comment: "I need to make a console application" - Do you? That's nice, but not a real question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [AlphaVSS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS/). I believe it's exactly what the doctor ordered.