# Volume Shadow Copy (VSS) sample in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, volume-shadow-service

I've seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673826/how-to-use-volume-shadow-copy-using-c-sharp-in-vs2008), but  I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement a system to read existing shadow copies from my system.

Can someone provide a short sample of code that lets me browse existing shadow copies using either the MS API or Alpha's?

FYI — [this is older code](http://alphavss.codeplex.com/workitem/8328) and not easily adaptable (or at least not from my perspective)

Comment: I've seen that and it doesn't really help me out.  The DLL he uses is no longer available.  I've installed the SDK, but there's no assistance there, either.   Additionally, that's VB, not C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [AlphaVSS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS). It is a wrapper around the Windows API calls. In particular, the "QuerySnapshots" function will be applicable to you.

In order to view the documentation you need to download AlphaVSS -- don't worry, it's free.

If you are looking for an example, download the source and look in `Alpha-1.2\Source\Samples`